# pointcut not working on methods with arguments

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I've added an annotation to track the time it takes a method to execute, but even though it executes for methods without parameters, it does not on methods with parameters.

```
@Around("@annotation(com.x.y.a.TrackTime)")
public Object trackTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return getProceedAndTrackTime(joinPoint);
}
```

I also tried using execution:

```
 @Around("execution(public void com.x.y.m.myMethod(..))")
```

also

```
@Around("execution(public void com.x.y.m.myMethod(com.x.y.e.SomeType))")
```

and also

```
 @Around("execution(public void com.x.y.m.myMethod(..)) && args(myArgument,..)")
```

None of the above works on methods with parameters, why is that? How should it be done?

Comment: Nobody can help you diagnose the problem if you only show pointcuts and not the target methods. I would be very surprised if what you say is true. Maybe you think it is because the methods have no parameters, but probably it is something else: They are not annotated, they are not public, they reside in classes which are no Spring beans/components etc. There are many possible reasons, your information is insufficient. As a user with 1,000+ reputation points you should know better how to ask questions. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To track the execution time of **a method with or without arguments**, you can try below `annotation` and implementation:

**Annotated interface:**

```
@Component
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TimeTracker {}
```

**And implementation of above interface**:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TimeTrackerAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(TimeTracker)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object obj = pJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("Total milli seconds in execution of method: " + pJoinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " is :" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And then wherever you use the annotation `@TimeTracker` total time will be printed, you can changes from sysout to logging

For details, I have also pushed my sample code into github, have a look into that at: https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/tree/master/springBoot/gs-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo